# site to site vpn between peers, all with dynamic ip?

Tags: vpn, dynamic-dns

How do I set up a site-to-site VPN between 2-6 sites, when all the peers are using dynamic IP? DynDNS (or equivalent) is set up on all sites, so accessing the IP from outside shouldn't be a problem. I'm guessing using pre-shared keys isn't a problem, because it's so few peers. I do however want a full mesh network.

I'm going to buy new equipment for all sites.

Is it possible to use a DNS name as the peer (I've only used static IP)?

Comment: I used IPSEC for full mesh VPN, I think it's possible with dynamic IPs too (though I myself use static IPs)... Was real pain to setup, but once set up, it works great.

Answer (score 0):

the whole point of dyndns-like services is the present a static dns name, whose IP pointer may change occasionally, so pointing to the DNS name should be reasonably reliable. there may be some drop in service when the ip changes and the router has not yet completed the update to the service provider however, which may require you to reconnect the tunnel.

Comment: I'm guessing that when the connection dies, either router will still have connectivity to the other one before dns updates, and it'll be able to set it up again. The DNS renewal should only take a second. If not, it should work just fine a minute later when the dns is updated. What i'm not sure of if weither you can use a dns name as a vpn peer, and what happens if you do.

Comment: you can in windows at least: http://i.technet.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC196158.gif  [Note that the image says "Host name or IP address"]

Comment: i always thought of hostname as netbios name, not dns name

Comment: no, it generically means hostname, with no assumptions as to the protocol. most NICs use a naming service lookup precedence, that tells the system what kinds of name services to query in what order. its usually something like 'hosts file, DNS, WINS, Broadcast'. if the address is found in hosts, it does not query DNS. if it is found in DNS, it doesn't try a wins server, and if its found in wins, it doesn't attempt to use the netbui broadcast resolution protocol.